# Java - Comparing returned Date(0) from null value from database

Tags: java, mongodb

What I will be doing is to get all records from my selected collection that has null `something_date`. In checking in mongo, it is "something_date" : null. But when retrieving those null `something_date` the returned is an Epoch date. I'm still figuring out how to check for that value instead of just doing:

```
    List<StudentDto> studentList = studentDao.select(new Properties(), true);
    for(StudentDto student : studentList){
        if(student.getSomethingDate() == null)  //getSomethingDate() returns Date
            System.out.println("SOMETHING DATE IS NULL");
        else
            System.out.println("SOMETHING DATE IS " + student.getSomethingDate);
    }
```

But this won't work since I've just found out that the null `something_date` from the DB will have a value in when retrieved in Java, the epoch 0 date. 
Does anyone have an idea on this matter? 
Your help is greatly appreaciated

EDIT: 
What i mean is that the returned date is this: 'Thu Jan 01 07:59:59 CST 1970' if the something_date from db is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
 if(student.getSomethingDate() == null || student.getSomethingDate().getTime () == 0)
```

EDIT:

```
 if(student.getSomethingDate() == null || student.getSomethingDate().getTime () == -1)
```

instead of ..getTime() == 0 is should be ..getTime() == -1 if i want to check for null dates in db that were replaced with Thu Jan 01 07:59:59 CST 1970 (or Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT)

Comment: Hmm what i mean is that the returned date is this: 'Thu Jan 01 07:59:59 CST 1970' if the something_date from db is null

Comment: Ain't epoch(0) then is it.  I had a case where the datetime was being stored in a DB with less then ms, so I had to alway multiply by 1000 - not related is it?

Comment: Hmm i think im confused with your comment and i think it's not related. But you're answer helped my problem. So instead of `..getTime() == 0` is should be `..getTime() == -1` if i want to check for null dates in db that were replaced with Thu Jan 01 07:59:59 CST 1970

Thanks!

Comment: sorry I did not catch the CST on your timestamp